# How to change class name and aria expanded with vba

Tags: excel, vba, wai-aria

i try to change class name and aria-expended in html with vba. but i locked.

I tried the code below but failed because I couldn't understand its logic.

İ need to change  to   and then aria-expanded="false" to aria-expanded="true"

```
Sub test()

    Dim IE As Object
    Dim doc As HTMLDocument
    Set IE = CreateObject("Internetexplorer.application")

    IE.Visible = True
    IE.navigate "https://sample/cat.php?taxonomy=category"

    Do While IE.Busy
        Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
    Loop

    Set doc = IE.document


    doc.getElementsByClassName("level-0").getElementsByTagName("td").getElementsByClassName("row-actions").Value = "row-actions visible"
    doc.getElementsByClassName("level-0").getElementsByTagName("td").getElementsByClassName("row-actions visible").getElementsByClassName ("button-link editinline")



Set IE = Nothing
End Sub
```

```
<tr class="level-0" id="tag-1">
 <td class="name column-name has-row-actions column-primary" data-colname="Name">
   <div class="row-actions">
     <span class="inline hide-if-no-js">
       <button class="button-link editinline" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Quick edit “cottage garden” inline" type="button">Quick&nbsp;Edit</button> 
.
.
.
```